# Find object index in binding list?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-8.0

How do you find the index of an object in a binding list? Below is my code:

```
public class Object
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int id { get; set; }
}
BindingList<Object> objectList = new BindingList<Object>();
```

I want to do something like `var int = objectList.FindIndex(a => a.Name == "Text");`
I've seen the use of `SingleOrDefault` from LINQ to find the object itself, but how can I find the index?

Comment: I'm currently using `objectList.ToList().FindIndex(a => a.Name == object.Name)`, and I'm wondering if there's a more succinct answer.

Comment: How could it be shorter than 1 method name with 1 parameter ?